# MySql comapre rows in same table if one row status value is 5

Tags: mysql, compare, similarity

Table stucture

| name | surname | phone | email | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jonh | Red | 123 | johnmail | 5 |
| Mary | Blue | 333 | marymail | 0 |
| Helen | Green | 234 | marymail | 0 |
| Jonh | Red | 123 | johnmail | 0 |

How can I compare these rows with name, surname, email and phone, and select (display) only Jonh Red because that row exist two time and one row have status 5?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try an aggregation approach here:

```sql
SELECT name, surname, phone, email
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY name, surname, phone, email
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND SUM(status = 5) > 0;
```

This would return every tuple (sans status values) which both appear in duplicate and also have a status value of 5 in at least one of the duplicates.

Comment: Thank you, nice answer.